# Change JavaScript Date in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, datetime

Without having to change the date/time of the computer I am debugging, is there a way, either via the dev tools or by running some custom JavaScript in the console, to set / change what time or date Google Chrome thinks it is?

IE so that `new Date()` returns what you've set the browser to think it is, rather than the system's date.

There are ways around it, but it would be handy to debug different dates / times.

Comment: No you can not change the browsers view of the Date

Comment: There are more things JS couldn't do. Here's a tip: If the thing you want to do may cause security problems, it probably can't be done in JS.

Comment: The specification simply says that a Date called with no arguments creates a Date for "[*the current time*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-value)". It is up to each implementation how they determine that, but using a host system call seems reasonable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is simply how to create a date for a specific date and time, which is default functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: override Date.prototype.constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839318/javascript-override-date-prototype-constructor)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use:

```
    var fake_date = new Date("October 6, 2016 11:13:00");

    //overriding date function
    Date = function(){return fake_date;};
    var new_date = new Date();
    alert(new_date);
```

Comment: What I am after is a setting in Chrome (or any browser for that matter) to set / override what `new Date()` returns, rather than actually change the JavaScript code itself.

Comment: Using the Date constructor to parse a string is the worst way to create a date.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Date.now is not a function` :/

Comment: @RobG Unless it's an ISO 8601 date string - then the result is unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks. This modified version fixes the Date.now bug:
`var fake_date = new Date("July 25, 2022 10:11:00");
//overriding date function
Date = function(){return fake_date;};
Date.now = () => fake_date.getTime()
var new_date = new Date();
alert(new_date);`

Answer (score 5):

You would need to write a function that wraps new Date and returns a modified version of the date. For example:

```
/**
 * Overwrite Date constructor with configurable current time
 * @param {object} Date         - The native Date object
 * @param {Number} year         - Optional. Default year to this.
 * @param {Number} month        - Optional. Default month to this.
 * @param {Number} day          - Optional. Default day to this.
 * @param {Number} minute       - Optional. Default minute to this.
 * @param {Number} second       - Optional. Default second to this.
 * @param {Number} milliseconds - Optional. Default milliseconds to this.
 */
Date = function (Date, year, month, day, hour, minute, second, milliseconds) {

    function MyDate() {

        // Get arguments passed into new Date()
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

        // Add null to start
        args.unshift(null);

        // Call new Date() with the original arguments
        var date = new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Date, args));

        if (typeof year !== 'undefined' && arguments.length === 0) {
            date.setFullYear(year);
        }

        if (typeof month !== 'undefined' && arguments.length === 0) {
            date.setMonth(month);
        }

        if (typeof day !== 'undefined' && (arguments.length === 0 || arguments.length === 2)) {
            date.setDate(day);
        }

        if (typeof hour !== 'undefined' && (arguments.length === 0 || arguments.length === 3)) {
            date.setHours(hour);
        }
        if (typeof minute !== 'undefined' && (arguments.length === 0 || arguments.length === 4)) {
            date.setMinutes(minute);
        }
        if (typeof second !== 'undefined' && (arguments.length === 0 || arguments.length === 5)) {
            date.setSeconds(second);
        }
        if (typeof milliseconds !== 'undefined' && (arguments.length === 0 || arguments.length === 6)) {
            date.setMilliseconds(milliseconds);
        }

        return date;
    }

    MyDate.prototype = Date.prototype;

    return MyDate;

}(Date);
```

On the last line you can specify values for overwriting the current time:

```
}(Date, 1990); // Year
}(Date, 1990, 05); // Year/month
}(Date, 1990, 05, 11); // Year/month/day
}(Date, 1990, 05, 11, 13); // Year/month/day Hour
}(Date, 1990, 05, 11, 13, 05); // Year/month/day Hour:minute
}(Date, 1990, 05, 11, 13, 05, 01); // Year/month/day Hour:minute:second
```

The benefit of this is that any existing new Date() calls with arguments still work correctly:

```
new Date(2001, 02, 03);
> Mar 03 2001
```

Also time is not frozen so the seconds value will increase with the normal clock:

```
// Year changed to 1990
console.log(new Date());
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(new Date());
}, 5000);

> Thu Oct 11 1990 17:02:17 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)
> Thu Oct 11 1990 17:02:22 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Comment: *setYear* is a legacy method, *setFullYear* should be used instead. Note that setting each parameter separately may result in a different result to setting them all at once, e.g. creating a date for 31 Jan then setting the month to 1 results in a Date for 2 or 3 March,  so `date.setFullYear(2016,10,1)` would be much preferred.

Comment: Close to what I'm after, but still requires a change to the code rather than configuration in the browser. Perhaps what is required is a browser extension...

Comment: I wonder if this works for RelativeTimeFormat https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/RelativeTimeFormat/RelativeTimeFormat

Comment: Unfortunately this kills the many Date methods that exist and are used nowadays. Otherwise the only answer that attempts an elegant solution where seconds still increment and so on.

Comment: bro wrote a whole library for a simple thing like that

Answer (score 0):

If you use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39909694/8210954), you might get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Date.now is not a function`. In that case, you can add `.now` as a method returning the timestamp integer for the fake date.

```js
const testDate = new Date('Fri Feb 11 2022 10:06:37 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)')
const returnTestDate = () => testDate
returnTestDate.now = () => testDate.getTime()
Date = returnTestDate

console.log(Date.now()) // returns 1644591997000 every time
```

Comment: Please don't post answers that are little more than links to other answers on Stack Overflow. If the questions are the same then flag one as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks though this version breaks `new Date()`. I commented on the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39909694/756177) that gets both parts to work. Thanks for the inspiration.

Answer (score -7):

Just use the `setTime` function:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(1332403882588);
```

The int parameter is the UNIX timestamp in milliseconds.

Comment: That creates a Date object for a specific moment in time, it does "*set / change what time or date Google Chrome thinks it is*".